# Jquery on Scroll move by sections

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website on which I don't want to use a normal scroller. I want a scroller that moves through sections. I have this full page sections on my code:

```
<section class="first">
</section>
<section class="second">
</section>
```

I want that when user scrolls down it goes automatically to section "second" and after another scroll that goes to "third", etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: By "scroller" do you mean scrollbar?

Comment: Yes  the scroll navigation, i have it disabled as overflow:hidden, but i want to make the scroll from mouse to go by sections and not like the normal scrollers

Comment: This might be a good place to start. But NOTE it does NOT work in safari. https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a button with the id button, try this example:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Used this to solved your problem

https://codepen.io/jvondoom/pen/VvbrdY